# Magento 2.3 Elastic Search 5+ Effecting Layered Navigation

Tags: magento2

With Elasticsearch built in with Magento 2.3 it's stopped allowing me to choose an option in the layered navigation, if i choose a filter the ajax gif shows but will not display any results.

If i disabled Elasticsearch and switched back to MySQL the filters work fine.

Any idea?